# Express 4 + Angular 2 HTML 5 Routing Concerns

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, angular

I am making a basic web app with Express 4 and Angular 2. Here, there is nothing specific to Angular 2 besides the fact I am using its HTML 5 router.

Here is the routing work flow of the app:

There are two main server side routing configurations of the app. Both look similar to this:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', authenticationHelpers.isAuth, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

/* GET login page. */
router.get('/login', authenticationHelpers.isNotAuth, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});
```

These manage explicitly, the two cases in which a user routes to `/` and `/login`.

However if the user is logged in and is able to visit `/` to render the index express view, there are HTML5 routes the user can take advantage of. These include urls like the following:

```
localhost:5000/user
localhost:5000/profile
localhost:5000/profile/settings
```

#### The issue

Clearly there is no `router.get('/user')`, and there shouldn't be, as this is all front-end work done by the Angular 2 router. However, to enable linking that would allow a user to simply type `localhost:5000/profile/settings`, and have the site route you to the index file (given that you were logged in) and THEN route you (with angular 2's HTML 5 routing) to your own `/profile/settings`I had to place this piece of code in my `app.js`:

```
app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

This gives me a big problem though. If you are not logged in and you are given the link `localhost:5000/profile/settings` it will render the index view because it only runs the `authenticationHelpers.isAuth` function on the `router.get('/')` routing code above. I would also love to be able to throw 404 errors on routes that don't exist in express, or angular.

However in my mind, to enable this functionality express would have to know about all the HTML 5 routing options as well as the express routing options. To me, this breaks the separation of routing concerns because if I changed an HTML 5 angular route, I'd also have to make a change in express (most likely, view the solution below). I'd like all this functionality, but without this information leaking between route handlers however I simply don't see a way around it. If anyone could help me figure out a better way to do this that would be great! If the information sharing or angular routes with express routes is the only way I've developed the most optimized lean solution I could below:

#### Potential Solution

```
router.get(['/', '/user/', '/profile/*'], authenticationHelpers.isAuth, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the end of all routes

```
app.all("/*", authenticationHelpers.isAuth, function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Should solve your problem